# Defining correct parameters & Passing an array in a recursive function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, binary-search, dev-c++

I am in an intro C++ class and I've had difficulties with defining correct parameters before, so if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

This assignment was to create a binary search function, in which the program will guess a number that the user is thinking of.

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int b_search(int Arry[], int L, int R)                
{
   int M = 0;                                         
   char userAnswer = '-';

   M = (L + R) / 2;


   cout << "Is it " << Arry[M] << "? (l/h/z): ";
   cin >> userAnswer;

   if( (userAnswer != 'l') && (userAnswer != 'h') ) { 
      cout << "Thank you!" << endl;                   
   }
   else {                                             
      if (userAnswer == 'l') {                        
        b_search(Arry[], L, M); 
      }
      else {                                          
        b_search(Arry[], ++M, R);                     
      }
   }
   return;      
}


int main()                                            
{
    const int N = 100;
    int A[N];
    int i = 0;
    int value = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
    {
        A[i] = value;
        ++value;
    }

   cout << "Choose a number from 1 to 100." << endl << endl;
   cout << "Answer with:" << endl;
   cout << "   l - if your num is lower" << endl;
   cout << "or: " << endl;
   cout << "   h - if your num is higher" << endl;
   cout << "or: " << endl;
   cout << "   any other key if the guess is right." << endl << endl;

   b_search(N, 1, 100)

   return 0;

}
```

When I compile this it has a problem with the first recursive call's 1st parameter.

This is the error message from Code Pad:

```
In function 'int b_search(int*, int, int)':
Line 22: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the square brackets when referring to an array by its name. Let's say you declare an array called `A`. Then:

`A`: is an array.

`A[5]`: is an element of `A`.

`A[]`: is not a valid expression.

Since you want to pass the array to the `b_search` function recursively, rather than any of its elements, just use `Arry`.

The `int Arry[]` in the function declaration is not an expression, but a *declarator* which declares the parameter `Arry`. Declarators resemble expressions in some ways, but have different syntax rules. `[]` means "array" in a declarator, but not in an expression.

There is a subtlety here associated with array parameters: when you declare a function to take an array parameter, the parameter's type is automatically rewritten to become a pointer instead. So `Arry` is actually a pointer, rather than an array. This detail is invisible to you in this case because arrays and pointers behave in the same way under subscripting and arrays are automatically converted to pointers when passed by value.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So when declaring functions you need declarators in the parameters and when calling functions you need expressions? It compiled correctly, except now there is a problem with the third parameter of my original call of b_search() in main(). It says "invalid conversion of int to int* ."

Comment: @Sarah Yes, you use declarators to declare parameters and variables as well as to write down types, but when actually calling functions you have to pass in expressions. And your error now is because you tried to pass in `N` as the array whereas you should've passed in `A`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It **is** an array. It only decays to a pointer because it's being passed by value, but it's an array first.

Comment: @Brian: No. `Arry` is the function argument — a _pointer_ — after the decay you speak of. `A` is an array.

Comment: Ohh I see now. Duh. I mis-read the error message. I thought it was referring to the third parameter for some reason. Thank you very much Brian you are very helpful!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Whoops, you're right, my bad. I'll edit it... a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You define `b_search` as taking in an int array, an int, and another int.  However, the first thing you do:

```
b_search(N, 1, 100); // Is invalid since N is an int but the function expects an array.
```

is try to pass in a const int, an int, and an int.  The first parameter is supposed to be an int array, not an int.

The other problem I see is inside the definition of your `b_search` where you try to recurs, you call `b_search` with the first parameter `Arry[]`.  The brackets are not valid, since `Arry` is already an array, you can just pass it in as is.

Comment: It's possible that initially passing `1` and `100` is wrong, too, since they're being used as indices to the array. It should be either `0` and `100` or possibly `0` and `99`, depending on how b_search is written.

Comment: No, it takes a pointer. Not an array. `Arry` is not an array.